# Cron Lock Timeout, when to use?

Tags: wp-cron

When is it a good idea to use this constant in relation to WordPress Cron?

WP_CRON_LOCK_TIMEOUT

Comment: As far as I can make out, `WP_CRON_LOCK_TIMEOUT` is already used by WordPress's `cron` functions. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Just trying to optimise my site, and I read that this can be useful for preventing stacking of cron jobs.